# SQL n to m table Composite Key and single indices

Tags: sql, composite-primary-key, indices

I've encountered a problem on a current task involving a simple n-to-m relation table.

In my table I have the following columns: 
(a): FK to table_a 
(b): FK to table_b

The usual approach would be to create a composite primary key on (a) & (b) giving me the ability to search efficient for: 
(a) 
(a) & (b)

But I also need to be able to search efficient for (b) alone. So in general this are my search scenarios:
(a) 
(b) 
(a) & (b)

Would it be better to create 
 1. a composite PK on (a) & (b) and another single index on (b)? 
 2. Or create two single indices  on both (a) and (b) and accept the fact that the search for (a) & (b) might not be as fast as it could (because it need to look up two seperate indices instead of one)?

Also in the future there might be (c) so then I would need to search for (a), (b), (c) or any combination between.

Anyone who had that problem in the past and knows a reasonable solution for that?

Edit: 
Additional requested information: 
table_b will be a lot larger than table_a, possibly round 10-20 times larger. 
Query percentages for the rows are expected to be around:
(a): 40% 
(b): 40% 
(a) & (b): 20%

Comment: That depends, How big is table_a vs. table_b ? Are the searches on (a), (b), (a)&(b) equally frequent?

Comment: Added expected values to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create two indexes, one a composite index on `(a, b)` and the other either only on `(b)` or on `b` and more columns.

If you are creating two indexes anyway, you are already incurring the costs of the two indexes.  Removing a column from an index is a small savings, relative to the overhead of maintaining the indexes.  You might as well have the indexes that work best on your queries.